# Get hyperlink text when clicked on dynamically generated anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html, python-2.7, sqlite

I am trying to display contents of sqllite table using **bottle** on html template file. And here is the handler code in the template file.

```
%for row in rows:
    <tr>
  %for col in row[0::2]:
        <td><div class="box"><a class="button" href="#popup1" id ="a1">{{col}}</a></div></td>
 %end
%end
```

It render the table as per the expectation on html page with three rows as data(please refer the below html source code which can be viewed on browser once the page is generated).

```
<tr><td><div class="box"><a class="button" href="#popup1" id ="a1">Testbatch1</a></div></td></tr>

<tr><td><div class="box"><a class="button" href="#popup1" id ="a1">Testbatch2</a></div></td></tr>

<tr><td><div class="box"><a class="button" href="#popup1" id ="a1">Testbatch3</a></div></td></tr>
```

Now I have written simple javascript code to display text on the link ie. value of **{{col}}** when it gets clicked

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var batch = document.getElementById("a1").innerHTML;
window.alert(batch)
</script>
```

Now problem is, when I click on any of the hyperlink, JS display
**Testbatch1** in alert window.

I have also tried with below code, but still geting the same output

```
$('a1').click(function(){
 window.alert($(this).text());
});
```

Can anyone suggest me how to get the hyperlink text of such dynamically generated anchor tags? My aim is to read the text of the hyperlink when clicked and send back to my python code where I will use it as paramter for sql query to render some other output.

Comment: 1) id's must be unique, 2) the second one will never fire because you don't have a `<a1>` tag.

Comment: @KevinKloet: Thanks Kevin, I was looking for root cause of such behaviour. Can you please tell me how can I get unique ID for such code?

Comment: in this case you don't need a id at all, you can use a class for example as you want to group them, if you give them the class "anchorClass" you can do something like `$('.anchorClass').click(function(){
 window.alert($(this).text());
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on link .button class event is occurred

```
$(document).on('click', ".button", function(){
   alert($(this).text())
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As Identifiers must be unique. You can't assign duplicate IDs. CSS class can be used for binding event handler. Here in snippet I have added `a1` class to anchor.

```
%for row in rows:
    <tr>
  %for col in row[0::2]:
        <td><div class="box"><a class="button a1" href="#popup1">{{col}}</a></div></td>
 %end
%end
```

And for binding event handler use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) method with [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) approach, when generating elements dynamically.

*Example*

```
$(document).on('click', ".a1", function(){
    alert($(this).text())
});
```

In place of `document` you should use closest static container.